# blazor foreach component update parent

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have this on my razor page:

```
 @foreach (AanmeldingItem ai in Aanmeldingen.Aanmeldingen)
      {
        <NieuweAanmeldingScherm Aanmelding=@ai SL=@SL />
      }
```

The component "NieuweAanmeldingScherm" has a bunch of divs and inputtexts to gather some data.
On the same page as the above foreach I have a button to add a new item.
When I click this button it adds a new "AanmeldingItem" to "Aanmeldingen.Aanmeldingen" which is a list of "AanmeldingItem".

My problem is that when I enter some data it is not updated to the item in the list.

How does this work in Blazor (I'm just starting with it)?

so basically:

```
@foreach (MyClass myclass in MyClasses) 
{
  <MyComponent Myclass=@myclass />
}
```

MyComponent:

```
<InputText @bind-value=@myclass.item1 />
<InputText @bind-value=@myclass.item2 />

@code 
{
  [parameter]
  public MyClass myclass {get;set;}

}
```

Add button on the page containing the foreach loop:

```
<div class="form-control nieuwAanmeldItem" @onclick="NieuwItem" />
```

How do I make it so that MyClasses is updated with the info from the inputtexts?

Comment: yes, there are about 5 fields. It is a form to add a vehicle to a list.

Comment: You can use [BlazorFiddle](https://blazorfiddle.com/) to create an example so we can understand what you try to do.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is missing a `@key` directive, which gives Blazor a way to identify each instance of the component when rendering.

```html
@foreach (AanmeldingItem ai in Aanmeldingen.Aanmeldingen)
{
  <NieuweAanmeldingScherm @key=ai Aanmelding=@ai SL=@SL />
}
```

Here, I have used the `AanmeldingItem` instance as the key, but if that class has a suitable unique `int,string` or some other simple type, use that instead as it will be better for performance.

Comment: Do you know what data, exactly, instance references as keys provide?  Does it calculate some kind of hash or what?

Comment: No, because that can vary depending on the objects involved - it uses `Equals(oldKey, newKey)` where  `oldKey` and `newKey` are defined as `object`, so the comparison depends on the type of the keys.

Comment: What's the default for that method given, say, a `foreach`  run against `List<MyClass>` with the key just being the instance?  I would expect that it would either be (1) just the pointer to each instance.  (2) some kind of default hash.  Is that wrong?

Comment: if the `@key` is of type `MyClass` I would expect a reference check - as long as MyClass doesn't override Equals - but I haven't looked at the default implementation to confirm.

Comment: This is definitely the right answer if you are looping through a collection and creating child components

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what I was doing wrong.

[Mister Magoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2658697/mister-magoo)'s answer wasn't really needed, but I implemented it anyway. According to Microsoft it should work automatically but now I'm sure it works.

The problem was that I re-initialised the parameter on the "NieuwAanmeldingScherm". This caused to sever the link with the list from the foreach in the parent.

So this is what I did:

```
  [Parameter]
  public AanmeldingItem Aanmelding { get; set; }

  protected override void OnInitialized()
  {
    Aanmelding = new AanmeldingItem();    

    base.OnInitialized();
  }
```

And that is wrong since the parameter is already initialized in the parent.

Comment: You really do need a `@key` to ensure consistency - it may look right but could go wrong without it - where did you get "according to Microsoft is should work automatically" from?

Comment: from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-6.0
Use @key to control the preservation of elements and components
When rendering a list of elements or components and the elements or components subsequently change, Blazor must decide which of the previous elements or components can be retained and how model objects should map to them. Normally, this process is automatic and can be ignored, but there are cases where you may want to control the process.

Comment: Ok, thanks - I might suggest they change that wording as it is misleading.

Comment: This is a better section of that page : [Typically, it makes sense to use @key whenever a list is rendered (for example, in a foreach block) and a suitable value exists to define the @key.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#when-to-use-key)